# Prevent PHP file being included if website is listed in Google search results

Tags: php, web-crawler, laravel-blade, google-search

working with a custom built click tracking solution within Laravel.

I have a PHP file that is included on each page that sends off an API call to another site that tracks each visit.

I've done plenty of work to make sure it ignores scrapers and crawlers etc but it's still firing everytime the website is shown within Google search results.

Is there something I can do that will be prevent this file being included unless its an actual visit?

Currently getting a lot of 'organic' visits tracking when its not a visit but instead just someone seeing the website listed on Google.

Thanks.

Comment: You are sure that it is shown within Google search results? Don't think Google connects to each and every site whenever it shows search-results. I think these are crawlers which you did not catch so far.

Comment: Show code for more clarity.

Comment: @Melvin Yeah definitely, I can test it myself by searching for my site and then see the visit tracked in the database.

Comment: With your IP or one of Google search?